# Identifying partitioned tables in the BigQuery web UI

Tags: google-bigquery

We have many tables, across many datasets and projects. Some are partitioned, and some are not. Our users sometimes can't tell if a table that they are looking at is partitioned or not. Users run something like the following SQL to work it out:

```
SELECT
_PARTITIONTIME AS pt
FROM
`<some_table>`
LIMIT 1
```

If it returns an error, then it's not partitioned.

Is there an easier way to detect if a table is partitioned or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to quickly identify if a table is partitioned or not in the web UI.

The first is by selecting the table details tab on the table. If it's partitioned then it will display *"Partitioned by Day"*

[image]

The second is by selecting the schema tab on the table. If it's partitioned then it will show the _"*PARTITIONTIME"* column in addition to the normal schema.

[image]